# sprintf usage with %.s

Tags: c, printf

While using sprintf like this

```
sprintf("%.40s",str);
```

I want to give a value like strlen(str) in place of 40.How do I do that? I tried replacing 40 with strlen(str), doesn't work. Giving a value like

```
#define len strlen(str)
```

and using %.len doesnt work either since %.len is used in "  ".

Comment: If strlen works for you then you have a NULL terminated string and you don't need to bother about a number to put for %s.If your string is not null terminated then anyways you will get wrong length.So it won't solve the purpose.

Answer (score 9):

Use `*` character.

```
sprintf(/* ... */, "%.*s", (int) strlen(str), str);
```

If you use C99, `snprintf` can also be suitable.

> **man printf (3)**
>   The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

Comment: Cast the result of `strlen` to an `int`, since that's the type a `*` expects. If `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(int)`, as it commonly is on 64-bit systems, you can have serious problems without the cast.

Answer (score 5):

As GajananH points out this is a pointless endevor:

For `strlen` to work, `str` must be NULL terminated.

If `str` is NULL terminated then:

```
sprintf(str2, "%.*s", strlen(str), str);
```

Is just an over complication of:

```
sprintf(str2, "%s", str);
```

Which itself is just an over complication of:

```
strcpy(str2, str);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand the point of using `strlen()`. If `strlen()` works for you, that means your string is NULL terminated and if the string is NULL terminated there is no real use of putting a number for `%s` (Unless you are trying to use a number smaller than the length of the string.

If your string is not NULL terminated then `strlen()` will return a wrong value and using that for `%s` will not help.

Instead I suggest you to use [**strnlen**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strnlen)() with a limit to the string length and use the return value for `%s`.